# Android Studio's emulator API level 31 (Android S) not turning its Bluetooth on

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth, android-emulator, android-api-levels

I'm trying to turn the Bluetooth on in android studio's emulator with API level 31 (Android S) but I can't.
When I click on the Bluetooth icon to turn it on, it remains on `Turning on...` and never changes to `on`.

[image]

I got the following logs filtered by the `bluetooth` keyword.

```
2022-01-19 15:33:27.822 504-2589/? D/BluetoothManagerService: enable(com.android.systemui):  mBluetooth =null mBinding = false mState = OFF
2022-01-19 15:33:27.824 504-540/? D/BluetoothManagerService: MESSAGE_ENABLE(0): mBluetooth = null
2022-01-19 15:33:27.825 504-540/? D/BluetoothManagerService: binding Bluetooth service
2022-01-19 15:33:27.831 504-2589/? D/BluetoothManagerService: enable returning
2022-01-19 15:33:27.903 504-550/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc 7284:com.android.bluetooth/1002 for service {com.android.bluetooth/com.android.bluetooth.btservice.AdapterService}
2022-01-19 15:33:27.980 7284-7284/? V/GraphicsEnvironment: ANGLE Developer option for 'com.android.bluetooth' set to: 'default'
2022-01-19 15:33:28.007 7284-7284/? D/BluetoothOppFileProvider: Initialized
2022-01-19 15:33:28.024 7284-7284/? V/AdapterServiceConfig: Adding BluetoothMapService
2022-01-19 15:33:28.024 7284-7284/? V/AdapterServiceConfig: Adding BluetoothOppService
2022-01-19 15:33:28.024 7284-7284/? V/AdapterServiceConfig: Adding BluetoothPbapService
2022-01-19 15:33:28.072 7284-7284/? I/BluetoothServiceJni: hal_util_load_bt_library: loaded Bluetooth library successfully
2022-01-19 15:33:28.073 7284-7284/? D/BluetoothAdapterService: onCreate()
2022-01-19 15:33:28.090 7284-7284/? D/BluetoothKeystoreService: new BluetoothKeystoreService isCommonCriteriaMode: false
2022-01-19 15:33:28.090 7284-7284/? D/BluetoothKeystoreService: start
2022-01-19 15:33:28.091 7284-7284/? I/droid.bluetoot: [0119/153328.091939:INFO:com_android_bluetooth_btservice_BluetoothKeystore.cpp(97)] classInitNative: succeeds
2022-01-19 15:33:28.092 7284-7284/? D/BluetoothKeystoreService: setBluetoothKeystoreService(): set to: com.android.bluetooth.btservice.bluetoothkeystore.BluetoothKeystoreService@2708c2e
2022-01-19 15:33:28.103 7284-7284/? D/BluetoothKeystoreService: loadConfigData
2022-01-19 15:33:28.118 7284-7284/? I/droid.bluetoot: [0119/153328.118849:INFO:com_android_bluetooth_btservice_ActivityAttribution.cpp(96)] classInitNative: succeeds
2022-01-19 15:33:28.119 7284-7284/? D/BluetoothKeystoreService: getCompareResult: 0
2022-01-19 15:33:28.122 7284-7284/? I/bt_btif: system/bt/btif/src/bluetooth.cc:162 init: init: start restricted = 0 ; common criteria mode = 0, config compare result = 0
2022-01-19 15:33:28.126 7284-7303/? I/bt_btif_core: system/bt/btif/src/btif_core.cc:235 btif_init_bluetooth: btif_init_bluetooth entered
2022-01-19 15:33:28.135 7284-7303/? I/bt_btif_core: system/bt/btif/src/btif_core.cc:239 btif_init_bluetooth: btif_init_bluetooth finished
2022-01-19 15:33:28.136 7284-7303/? I/bt_stack_config: system/bt/main/stack_config.cc:51 init: init attempt to load stack conf from /etc/bluetooth/bt_stack.conf
2022-01-19 15:33:28.136 7284-7284/? I/bt_btif: system/bt/btif/src/bluetooth.cc:417 get_profile_interface: get_profile_interface: id = socket
2022-01-19 15:33:28.140 7284-7284/? D/BluetoothKeystoreService: initJni()
2022-01-19 15:33:28.141 7284-7284/? I/bt_btif: system/bt/btif/src/bluetooth.cc:417 get_profile_interface: get_profile_interface: id = bluetooth_keystore
2022-01-19 15:33:28.142 7284-7284/? I/bt_btif: system/bt/btif/src/bluetooth.cc:417 get_profile_interface: get_profile_interface: id = sdp
2022-01-19 15:33:28.146 7284-7284/? D/BluetoothDatabase: start()
2022-01-19 15:33:28.156 7284-7284/? D/BluetoothDatabase: Load Database
2022-01-19 15:33:28.156 7284-7284/? I/BluetoothAdapterService: Phone policy enabled
2022-01-19 15:33:28.158 7284-7284/? D/BluetoothActiveDeviceManager: start()
2022-01-19 15:33:28.173 7284-7312/? D/BluetoothActiveDeviceManager: onAudioDevicesAdded
2022-01-19 15:33:28.173 7284-7312/? D/BluetoothActiveDeviceManager: Audio device added: sdk_gphone64_x86_64 type: 2
2022-01-19 15:33:28.173 7284-7312/? D/BluetoothActiveDeviceManager: Audio device added: sdk_gphone64_x86_64 type: 18
2022-01-19 15:33:28.173 7284-7312/? D/BluetoothActiveDeviceManager: Audio device added: sdk_gphone64_x86_64 type: 15
2022-01-19 15:33:28.173 7284-7312/? D/BluetoothActiveDeviceManager: Audio device added: sdk_gphone64_x86_64 type: 18
2022-01-19 15:33:28.173 7284-7312/? D/BluetoothActiveDeviceManager: Audio device added: sdk_gphone64_x86_64 type: 25
2022-01-19 15:33:28.173 7284-7312/? D/BluetoothActiveDeviceManager: Audio device added: sdk_gphone64_x86_64 type: 16
2022-01-19 15:33:28.174 7284-7284/? D/BluetoothAdapterService: setAdapterService() - trying to set service to com.android.bluetooth.btservice.AdapterService@7660ffb
2022-01-19 15:33:28.180 7284-7311/? D/BluetoothDatabase: compactLastConnectionTime: Compacting metadata after load
2022-01-19 15:33:28.180 7284-7311/? I/BluetoothDatabase: cacheMetadata
2022-01-19 15:33:28.187 7284-7284/? D/BluetoothAdapterService: onBind()
2022-01-19 15:33:28.188 504-504/? D/BluetoothManagerService: BluetoothServiceConnection: com.android.bluetooth.btservice.AdapterService
2022-01-19 15:33:28.188 504-540/? D/BluetoothManagerService: MESSAGE_BLUETOOTH_SERVICE_CONNECTED: 1
2022-01-19 15:33:28.191 504-540/? D/BluetoothManagerService: Broadcasting onBluetoothServiceUp() to 6 receivers.
2022-01-19 15:33:28.192 716-743/? D/BluetoothAdapter: onBluetoothServiceUp: android.bluetooth.IBluetooth$Stub$Proxy@989c5e7
2022-01-19 15:33:28.192 2064-2087/? D/BluetoothAdapter: onBluetoothServiceUp: android.bluetooth.IBluetooth$Stub$Proxy@d223d9a
2022-01-19 15:33:28.192 504-540/? D/BluetoothAdapter: onBluetoothServiceUp: android.bluetooth.IBluetooth$Stub$Proxy@57d7e
2022-01-19 15:33:28.192 1016-1959/? D/BluetoothAdapter: onBluetoothServiceUp: android.bluetooth.IBluetooth$Stub$Proxy@6c8758f
2022-01-19 15:33:28.194 7284-7296/? D/BluetoothAdapter: onBluetoothServiceUp: com.android.bluetooth.btservice.AdapterService$AdapterServiceBinder@ff327db
2022-01-19 15:33:28.201 919-2159/? D/BluetoothAdapter: onBluetoothServiceUp: android.bluetooth.IBluetooth$Stub$Proxy@ee58ce7
2022-01-19 15:33:28.202 7284-7295/? D/BluetoothAdapterService: enable() - Enable called with quiet mode status =  false
2022-01-19 15:33:28.203 504-540/? D/BluetoothManagerService: MESSAGE_GET_NAME_AND_ADDRESS
2022-01-19 15:33:28.203 7284-7299/? D/BluetoothAdapterService: updateAdapterState() - Broadcasting state BLE_TURNING_ON to 1 receivers.
2022-01-19 15:33:28.205 504-540/? D/BluetoothManagerService: MESSAGE_BLUETOOTH_STATE_CHANGE: OFF > BLE_TURNING_ON
2022-01-19 15:33:28.205 504-540/? D/BluetoothManagerService: Sending BLE State Change: OFF > BLE_TURNING_ON
2022-01-19 15:33:28.213 7284-7299/? D/BluetoothAdapterService: bleOnProcessStart()
2022-01-19 15:33:28.220 7284-7299/? D/BluetoothAdapterService: bleOnProcessStart() - Make Bond State Machine
2022-01-19 15:33:28.220 7284-7299/? D/BluetoothBondStateMachine: make
2022-01-19 15:33:28.247 7284-7318/? I/BluetoothBondStateMachine: StableState(): Entering Off State
2022-01-19 15:33:28.274 7284-7284/? I/bt_btif: system/bt/btif/src/bluetooth.cc:417 get_profile_interface: get_profile_interface: id = gatt
2022-01-19 15:33:31.257 7284-7306/? I/BtStopWatchLegacy: system/bt/common/stop_watch_legacy.cc:59 DumpStopWatchLog: bluetooth stopwatch log history:
2022-01-19 15:33:31.257 7284-7306/? A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 7306 (alarm_default_c), pid 7284 (droid.bluetooth)
2022-01-19 15:33:31.839 7325-7325/? A/DEBUG: Cmdline: com.android.bluetooth
2022-01-19 15:33:31.839 7325-7325/? A/DEBUG: pid: 7284, tid: 7306, name: alarm_default_c  >>> com.android.bluetooth <<<
2022-01-19 15:33:31.839 7325-7325/? A/DEBUG:       #01 pc 0000000000361ba8  /system/lib64/libbluetooth.so (startup_timer_expired(void*)+200) (BuildId: 978791ce22d770815df6a07cc81aa64e)
2022-01-19 15:33:31.839 7325-7325/? A/DEBUG:       #02 pc 000000000045452c  /system/lib64/libbluetooth.so (alarm_ready_generic(alarm_t*, std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&)+380) (BuildId: 978791ce22d770815df6a07cc81aa64e)
2022-01-19 15:33:31.839 7325-7325/? A/DEBUG:       #03 pc 0000000000454377  /system/lib64/libbluetooth.so (alarm_queue_ready(fixed_queue_t*, void*)+119) (BuildId: 978791ce22d770815df6a07cc81aa64e)
2022-01-19 15:33:31.839 7325-7325/? A/DEBUG:       #04 pc 0000000000458594  /system/lib64/libbluetooth.so (internal_dequeue_ready(void*)+84) (BuildId: 978791ce22d770815df6a07cc81aa64e)
2022-01-19 15:33:31.839 7325-7325/? A/DEBUG:       #05 pc 0000000000459ac2  /system/lib64/libbluetooth.so (run_reactor(reactor_t*, int)+450) (BuildId: 978791ce22d770815df6a07cc81aa64e)
2022-01-19 15:33:31.839 7325-7325/? A/DEBUG:       #06 pc 00000000004598d4  /system/lib64/libbluetooth.so (reactor_start(reactor_t*)+84) (BuildId: 978791ce22d770815df6a07cc81aa64e)
2022-01-19 15:33:31.839 7325-7325/? A/DEBUG:       #07 pc 000000000045b60a  /system/lib64/libbluetooth.so (run_thread(void*)+282) (BuildId: 978791ce22d770815df6a07cc81aa64e)
2022-01-19 15:33:31.990 504-504/? D/BluetoothManagerService: BluetoothServiceConnection, disconnected: com.android.bluetooth.btservice.AdapterService
2022-01-19 15:33:31.991 504-540/? E/BluetoothManagerService: MESSAGE_BLUETOOTH_SERVICE_DISCONNECTED(1)
2022-01-19 15:33:31.991 504-540/? D/BluetoothManagerService: Broadcasting onBluetoothServiceDown() to 5 receivers.
2022-01-19 15:33:31.991 716-2799/? D/BluetoothAdapter: onBluetoothServiceDown
2022-01-19 15:33:31.991 1016-1337/? D/BluetoothAdapter: onBluetoothServiceDown
2022-01-19 15:33:31.992 504-533/? I/ActivityManager: Process com.android.bluetooth (pid 7284) has died: psvc PER 
2022-01-19 15:33:31.993 504-540/? D/BluetoothAdapter: onBluetoothServiceDown
2022-01-19 15:33:31.993 919-2159/? D/BluetoothAdapter: onBluetoothServiceDown
2022-01-19 15:33:31.996 504-533/? W/ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service com.android.bluetooth/.btservice.AdapterService in 1000ms for connection
2022-01-19 15:33:31.997 2064-2087/? D/BluetoothAdapter: onBluetoothServiceDown
2022-01-19 15:33:33.026 504-550/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc 7343:com.android.bluetooth/1002 for service {com.android.bluetooth/com.android.bluetooth.btservice.AdapterService}
2022-01-19 15:33:33.096 7343-7343/? V/GraphicsEnvironment: ANGLE Developer option for 'com.android.bluetooth' set to: 'default'
2022-01-19 15:33:33.121 7343-7343/? D/BluetoothOppFileProvider: Initialized
2022-01-19 15:33:33.138 7343-7343/? V/AdapterServiceConfig: Adding BluetoothMapService
2022-01-19 15:33:33.138 7343-7343/? V/AdapterServiceConfig: Adding BluetoothOppService
2022-01-19 15:33:33.138 7343-7343/? V/AdapterServiceConfig: Adding BluetoothPbapService
2022-01-19 15:33:33.175 7343-7343/? I/BluetoothServiceJni: hal_util_load_bt_library: loaded Bluetooth library successfully
2022-01-19 15:33:33.176 7343-7343/? D/BluetoothAdapterService: onCreate()
2022-01-19 15:33:33.191 7343-7343/? D/BluetoothKeystoreService: new BluetoothKeystoreService isCommonCriteriaMode: false
2022-01-19 15:33:33.192 7343-7343/? D/BluetoothKeystoreService: start
2022-01-19 15:33:33.196 7343-7343/? I/droid.bluetoot: [0119/153333.195997:INFO:com_android_bluetooth_btservice_BluetoothKeystore.cpp(97)] classInitNative: succeeds
2022-01-19 15:33:33.196 7343-7343/? D/BluetoothKeystoreService: setBluetoothKeystoreService(): set to: com.android.bluetooth.btservice.bluetoothkeystore.BluetoothKeystoreService@2708c2e
2022-01-19 15:33:33.199 7343-7343/? D/BluetoothKeystoreService: loadConfigData
2022-01-19 15:33:33.212 7343-7343/? I/droid.bluetoot: [0119/153333.212428:INFO:com_android_bluetooth_btservice_ActivityAttribution.cpp(96)] classInitNative: succeeds
2022-01-19 15:33:33.212 7343-7343/? D/BluetoothKeystoreService: getCompareResult: 0
2022-01-19 15:33:33.216 7343-7343/? I/bt_btif: system/bt/btif/src/bluetooth.cc:162 init: init: start restricted = 0 ; common criteria mode = 0, config compare result = 0
2022-01-19 15:33:33.225 7343-7361/? I/bt_btif_core: system/bt/btif/src/btif_core.cc:235 btif_init_bluetooth: btif_init_bluetooth entered
2022-01-19 15:33:33.226 7343-7361/? I/bt_btif_core: system/bt/btif/src/btif_core.cc:239 btif_init_bluetooth: btif_init_bluetooth finished
2022-01-19 15:33:33.228 7343-7361/? I/bt_stack_config: system/bt/main/stack_config.cc:51 init: init attempt to load stack conf from /etc/bluetooth/bt_stack.conf
2022-01-19 15:33:33.229 7343-7343/? I/bt_btif: system/bt/btif/src/bluetooth.cc:417 get_profile_interface: get_profile_interface: id = socket
2022-01-19 15:33:33.238 7343-7343/? D/BluetoothKeystoreService: initJni()
2022-01-19 15:33:33.239 7343-7343/? I/bt_btif: system/bt/btif/src/bluetooth.cc:417 get_profile_interface: get_profile_interface: id = bluetooth_keystore
2022-01-19 15:33:33.240 7343-7343/? I/bt_btif: system/bt/btif/src/bluetooth.cc:417 get_profile_interface: get_profile_interface: id = sdp
2022-01-19 15:33:33.247 7343-7343/? D/BluetoothDatabase: start()
2022-01-19 15:33:33.248 7343-7343/? D/BluetoothDatabase: Load Database
2022-01-19 15:33:33.249 7343-7343/? I/BluetoothAdapterService: Phone policy enabled
2022-01-19 15:33:33.251 7343-7343/? D/BluetoothActiveDeviceManager: start()
2022-01-19 15:33:33.264 7343-7369/? D/BluetoothDatabase: compactLastConnectionTime: Compacting metadata after load
2022-01-19 15:33:33.264 7343-7369/? I/BluetoothDatabase: cacheMetadata
2022-01-19 15:33:33.272 7343-7370/? D/BluetoothActiveDeviceManager: onAudioDevicesAdded
2022-01-19 15:33:33.273 7343-7370/? D/BluetoothActiveDeviceManager: Audio device added: sdk_gphone64_x86_64 type: 2
2022-01-19 15:33:33.273 7343-7370/? D/BluetoothActiveDeviceManager: Audio device added: sdk_gphone64_x86_64 type: 18
2022-01-19 15:33:33.273 7343-7370/? D/BluetoothActiveDeviceManager: Audio device added: sdk_gphone64_x86_64 type: 15
2022-01-19 15:33:33.273 7343-7370/? D/BluetoothActiveDeviceManager: Audio device added: sdk_gphone64_x86_64 type: 18
2022-01-19 15:33:33.273 7343-7370/? D/BluetoothActiveDeviceManager: Audio device added: sdk_gphone64_x86_64 type: 25
2022-01-19 15:33:33.273 7343-7343/? D/BluetoothAdapterService: setAdapterService() - trying to set service to com.android.bluetooth.btservice.AdapterService@7660ffb
2022-01-19 15:33:33.274 7343-7370/? D/BluetoothActiveDeviceManager: Audio device added: sdk_gphone64_x86_64 type: 16
2022-01-19 15:33:33.287 7343-7343/? D/BluetoothAdapterService: onBind()
2022-01-19 15:33:33.288 504-504/? D/BluetoothManagerService: BluetoothServiceConnection: com.android.bluetooth.btservice.AdapterService
2022-01-19 15:33:33.289 504-540/? D/BluetoothManagerService: MESSAGE_BLUETOOTH_SERVICE_CONNECTED: 1
2022-01-19 15:33:33.292 504-540/? D/BluetoothManagerService: Broadcasting onBluetoothServiceUp() to 6 receivers.
2022-01-19 15:33:33.296 716-756/? D/BluetoothAdapter: onBluetoothServiceUp: android.bluetooth.IBluetooth$Stub$Proxy@82744a9
2022-01-19 15:33:33.297 2064-2087/? D/BluetoothAdapter: onBluetoothServiceUp: android.bluetooth.IBluetooth$Stub$Proxy@57556cb
2022-01-19 15:33:33.298 1016-1959/? D/BluetoothAdapter: onBluetoothServiceUp: android.bluetooth.IBluetooth$Stub$Proxy@8827d99
2022-01-19 15:33:33.299 7343-7355/? D/BluetoothAdapter: onBluetoothServiceUp: com.android.bluetooth.btservice.AdapterService$AdapterServiceBinder@ff327db
2022-01-19 15:33:33.300 504-540/? D/BluetoothAdapter: onBluetoothServiceUp: android.bluetooth.IBluetooth$Stub$Proxy@cfc5a20
2022-01-19 15:33:33.304 7343-7355/? D/BluetoothAdapterService: enable() - Enable called with quiet mode status =  false
2022-01-19 15:33:33.307 7343-7358/? D/BluetoothAdapterService: updateAdapterState() - Broadcasting state BLE_TURNING_ON to 1 receivers.
2022-01-19 15:33:33.308 919-2159/? D/BluetoothAdapter: onBluetoothServiceUp: android.bluetooth.IBluetooth$Stub$Proxy@a559094
2022-01-19 15:33:33.317 7343-7358/? D/BluetoothAdapterService: bleOnProcessStart()
2022-01-19 15:33:33.321 7343-7358/? D/BluetoothAdapterService: bleOnProcessStart() - Make Bond State Machine
2022-01-19 15:33:33.321 7343-7358/? D/BluetoothBondStateMachine: make
2022-01-19 15:33:33.323 7343-7376/? I/BluetoothBondStateMachine: StableState(): Entering Off State
2022-01-19 15:33:33.333 7343-7343/? I/bt_btif: system/bt/btif/src/bluetooth.cc:417 get_profile_interface: get_profile_interface: id = gatt
2022-01-19 15:33:36.247 7343-7364/? I/BtStopWatchLegacy: system/bt/common/stop_watch_legacy.cc:59 DumpStopWatchLog: bluetooth stopwatch log history:
2022-01-19 15:33:36.248 7343-7364/? A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 7364 (alarm_default_c), pid 7343 (droid.bluetooth)
2022-01-19 15:33:36.320 504-540/? E/BluetoothManagerService: waitForState [12] time out
2022-01-19 15:33:36.320 504-540/? D/BluetoothManagerService: Sending off request.
2022-01-19 15:33:36.336 7343-7353/? D/BluetoothAdapterService: disable() called with mRunningProfiles.size() = 1
2022-01-19 15:33:36.337 504-540/? D/BluetoothManagerService: MESSAGE_GET_NAME_AND_ADDRESS
2022-01-19 15:33:36.356 504-540/? D/BluetoothManagerService: MESSAGE_BLUETOOTH_STATE_CHANGE: OFF > BLE_TURNING_ON
2022-01-19 15:33:36.356 504-540/? D/BluetoothManagerService: Sending BLE State Change: OFF > BLE_TURNING_ON
2022-01-19 15:33:36.357 504-540/? D/BluetoothManagerService: MESSAGE_RESTART_BLUETOOTH_SERVICE: retry count=7
2022-01-19 15:33:36.357 504-540/? E/BluetoothManagerService: Reach maximum retry to restart Bluetooth!
2022-01-19 15:33:36.659 7383-7383/? A/DEBUG: Cmdline: com.android.bluetooth
2022-01-19 15:33:36.659 7383-7383/? A/DEBUG: pid: 7343, tid: 7364, name: alarm_default_c  >>> com.android.bluetooth <<<
2022-01-19 15:33:36.659 7383-7383/? A/DEBUG:       #01 pc 0000000000361ba8  /system/lib64/libbluetooth.so (startup_timer_expired(void*)+200) (BuildId: 978791ce22d770815df6a07cc81aa64e)
2022-01-19 15:33:36.659 7383-7383/? A/DEBUG:       #02 pc 000000000045452c  /system/lib64/libbluetooth.so (alarm_ready_generic(alarm_t*, std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&)+380) (BuildId: 978791ce22d770815df6a07cc81aa64e)
2022-01-19 15:33:36.659 7383-7383/? A/DEBUG:       #03 pc 0000000000454377  /system/lib64/libbluetooth.so (alarm_queue_ready(fixed_queue_t*, void*)+119) (BuildId: 978791ce22d770815df6a07cc81aa64e)
2022-01-19 15:33:36.659 7383-7383/? A/DEBUG:       #04 pc 0000000000458594  /system/lib64/libbluetooth.so (internal_dequeue_ready(void*)+84) (BuildId: 978791ce22d770815df6a07cc81aa64e)
2022-01-19 15:33:36.659 7383-7383/? A/DEBUG:       #05 pc 0000000000459ac2  /system/lib64/libbluetooth.so (run_reactor(reactor_t*, int)+450) (BuildId: 978791ce22d770815df6a07cc81aa64e)
2022-01-19 15:33:36.659 7383-7383/? A/DEBUG:       #06 pc 00000000004598d4  /system/lib64/libbluetooth.so (reactor_start(reactor_t*)+84) (BuildId: 978791ce22d770815df6a07cc81aa64e)
2022-01-19 15:33:36.659 7383-7383/? A/DEBUG:       #07 pc 000000000045b60a  /system/lib64/libbluetooth.so (run_thread(void*)+282) (BuildId: 978791ce22d770815df6a07cc81aa64e)
2022-01-19 15:33:36.713 504-2725/? I/ActivityManager: Process com.android.bluetooth (pid 7343) has died: psvc PER 
2022-01-19 15:33:36.717 504-2725/? W/ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service com.android.bluetooth/.btservice.AdapterService in 5400000ms for connection
2022-01-19 15:33:36.726 504-504/? D/BluetoothManagerService: BluetoothServiceConnection, disconnected: com.android.bluetooth.btservice.AdapterService
2022-01-19 15:33:36.729 504-540/? E/BluetoothManagerService: MESSAGE_BLUETOOTH_SERVICE_DISCONNECTED(1)
2022-01-19 15:33:36.731 504-540/? D/BluetoothManagerService: Broadcasting onBluetoothServiceDown() to 5 receivers.
2022-01-19 15:33:36.731 2064-2087/? D/BluetoothAdapter: onBluetoothServiceDown
2022-01-19 15:33:36.731 716-2060/? D/BluetoothAdapter: onBluetoothServiceDown
2022-01-19 15:33:36.732 1016-1959/? D/BluetoothAdapter: onBluetoothServiceDown
2022-01-19 15:33:36.732 504-540/? D/BluetoothAdapter: onBluetoothServiceDown
2022-01-19 15:33:36.732 919-2159/? D/BluetoothAdapter: onBluetoothServiceDown
```

Any idea how to fix this problem, please?

Answer (score -2):

You can't. The emulator does not support Bluetooth, as mentioned in the SDK's docs and several other places. Android emulator does not have bluetooth capabilities". You can only use real devices.

Comment: It is true that we can't use the Bluetooth on the Android Studio's emulator to test the connection with real android devices, but at least you can turn the Bluetooth and get a list of fake Bluetooth devices. I can do this in android studio's emulator with API level 30 as shown in this screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/HmmIF7K_d.webp?maxwidth=760&fidelity=grand

Comment: @MohamedMedhat Bluetooth permissions changed with Android 12. That could be the problem. [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions)

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. But this isn't the problem right now. The actual problem is that I can't even turn the Bluetooth of the emulator using the system itself. I'm not running any app. Instead, I dragged the status bar and pressed on the Bluetooth icon, then faced this problem.